# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace' when trying to replace

Tags: python

I am trying to make a hangman-type game and while replacing the underscores with the guessed letter, I receive

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace' error.

here is my Code:

```
import random
lines = open('file.txt').read().splitlines()
word =random.choice(lines)
print(word)

a = len(word)
print(a)

turn = 0


def convert_letter(word):
    new_word = word
    for i in range(0, len(word)):
        if ord(word[i]) != 32:
            new_word = new_word.replace(word[i], '_ ')
    print(new_word)
hidden = convert_letter(word)


def guessing():
  letterguess = ""
  letterguess = input("what is your guess ")
  if letterguess in word:
    
    print(word.find(letterguess))
    

    
    replaced_text = hidden.replace('_', letterguess)
    return(replaced_text)
  else:
    print ("no")
    guessing()
    
guessing()
```

Comment: `hidden` is `None` because `convert_letter` does not return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def convert_letter(word):
    new_word = word
    for i in range(0, len(word)):
        if ord(word[i]) != 32:
            new_word = new_word.replace(word[i], '_ ')
    return(new_word)
```

The main reason it doesn't work is because it never returns a value, it just prints it.

Comment: im sorry if this is dumb but how would I use new_word later on as a variable

Comment: @fier exactly how you've been using it! `hidden = convert_letter(word)`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in order to send a function's result back to the caller (in this case, the variable `hidden`), we have to use the `return` statement. Otherwise, the function will return `None` by default.

```
def convert_letter(word):
    new_word = word
    for i in range(0, len(word)):
        if ord(word[i]) != 32:
            new_word = new_word.replace(word[i], '_ ')
    print(new_word)              # No return statement
hidden = convert_letter(word)    # This will return hidden = None
```

To return the value of the variable `new_word` I would do this:

```
def convert_letter(word):
    new_word = word
    for i in range(0, len(word)):
        if ord(word[i]) != 32:
            new_word = new_word.replace(word[i], '_ ')
    print(new_word)
    return new_word              # Return statement
hidden = convert_letter(word)    # This will return hidden = new_word
```